# IBrokers twsFOP call in R

Tags: r, ibrokers

I'm trying to get the following to pull some data from IB (Nasdaq 100 e-mini futures options data). I am using the snapShot callback (included below). Could someone tell me what is wrong with my code?

```
require(IBrokers)
tws <- twsConnect()
test3<- twsFOP("NQ","GLOBEX",expiry="20141121",strike="4000",right="C")
test4 <- reqMktData(tws, test3, eventWrapper=eWrapper.data(length(1)),CALLBACK=snapShot)
```

Thanks a bunch. I've searched high and low online and found little documentation on twsFOP, besides the CRAN documentation which points to twsFuture. Snapshot call included below:

```
snapShot <- function (twsCon, eWrapper, timestamp, file, playback = 1, ...)
{
  if (missing(eWrapper))
    eWrapper <- eWrapper()
  names(eWrapper$.Data$data) <- eWrapper$.Data$symbols
  con <- twsCon[[1]]
  if (inherits(twsCon, "twsPlayback")) {
    sys.time <- NULL
    while (TRUE) {
      if (!is.null(timestamp)) {
        last.time <- sys.time
        sys.time <- as.POSIXct(strptime(paste(readBin(con,
                                                      character(), 2), collapse = " "), timestamp))
        if (!is.null(last.time)) {
          Sys.sleep((sys.time - last.time) * playback)
        }
        curMsg <- .Internal(readBin(con, "character",
                                    1L, NA_integer_, TRUE, FALSE))
        if (length(curMsg) < 1)
          next
        processMsg(curMsg, con, eWrapper, format(sys.time,
                                                 timestamp), file, ...)
      }
      else {
        curMsg <- readBin(con, character(), 1)
        if (length(curMsg) < 1)
          next
        processMsg(curMsg, con, eWrapper, timestamp,
                   file, ...)
        if (curMsg == .twsIncomingMSG$REAL_TIME_BARS)
          Sys.sleep(5 * playback)
      }
    }
  }
  else {
    while (TRUE) {
      socketSelect(list(con), FALSE, NULL)
      curMsg <- .Internal(readBin(con, "character", 1L,
                                  NA_integer_, TRUE, FALSE))
      if (!is.null(timestamp)) {
        processMsg(curMsg, con, eWrapper, format(Sys.time(),
                                                 timestamp), file, ...)
      }
      else {
        processMsg(curMsg, con, eWrapper, timestamp,
                   file, ...)
      }
      if (!any(sapply(eWrapper$.Data$data, is.na)))
        return(do.call(rbind, lapply(eWrapper$.Data$data,
                                     as.data.frame)))
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: what happens when you try and run?

Comment: Looks right to me. I [implemented this exact same function](https://r-forge.r-project.org/scm/viewvc.php/pkg/twsInstrument/R/get_quote.R?view=markup&root=twsinstrument) and I know it works for futures, options, equities, and FX (I haven't tried FOP). When I run your code, I'm able to connect to the market data farm. You're not going to get any data until there is a price change in the market.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function is not going to return until there is a price update.

If I change the instrument to a future, it works just fine.

```
test3<- twsFUT("NQ","GLOBEX",expiry="20141219")
test4 <- reqMktData(tws, test3, eventWrapper=eWrapper.data(length(1)),CALLBACK=snapShot)
test4
#     BidSize BidPrice AskPrice AskSize    Last LastSize Volume
#NQZ4      14     3984  3984.25       1 3984.25       11   1702
```

Your FOP instrument appears to be valid because you can call `reqContractDetails(tws, test3)` and you get back all the contract details.

Finally, using the market data call with the FOP contract looks like it is correct as well. I'm able to connect to the market data farm using your code...

```
test3<- twsFOP("NQ","GLOBEX",expiry="20141121",strike="4000",right="C")
reqMktData(tws, test3, eventWrapper=eWrapper.data(length(1)),CALLBACK=snapShot)
#2 -1 2104 Market data farm connection is OK:usfuture 
#2 -1 2106 HMDS data farm connection is OK:ushmds.us 
#2 -1 2107 HMDS data farm connection is inactive but should be available upon demand.cashhmds 
#2 -1 2106 HMDS data farm connection is OK:ushmds
```

Now we just need to wait until there is a price update.

---

If you want the last price without waiting for an update, you can pull it using `reqHistoricalData`, with the current time as the `endDateTime`.  If you want data for the Bid, Ask, and Trades, then you have to make 3 separate requests.  Here's how to get the last trade from the historical data service

```
dat <- reqHistoricalData(tws, test3, 
                  endDateTime=paste(format(Sys.time(), "%Y%m%d %H:%M:%S")), 
                  barSize="1 min", 
                  duration="5 D", useRTH=0, whatToShow="TRADES")
#waiting for TWS reply on NQ .... done.
last(dat)
#                    NQX4 C4000.Open NQX4 C4000.High NQX4 C4000.Low NQX4 C4000.Close NQX4 C4000.Volume NQX4 C4000.WAP
2014-10-01 16:14:00          101.75          101.75         101.75           101.75                 0         101.75
                    NQX4 C4000.hasGaps NQX4 C4000.Count
2014-10-01 16:14:00                  0                0
```

You'd need to use `whatToShow="BID"` and `whatToShow="ASK"` to get Bid and Ask data.

Comment: Thanks all for the help. Might it be possible to get the last price or better, the current bid or ask price, without waiting for a new price update?

Comment: @jd8585 Not really.  You can `reqHistoricalData`.  I'll update the answer.